# Degree Fahrenheit/Celsius Symbols ASCII NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

How can I represent the **Degree Fahrenheit** symbol in an NSString? The following code will produce a degree symbol and then the capital letter F, but is there an actual as Fahrenheit itself? Similarly, is there one for **Degree Celsius**?

```
NSString *fahrenheit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@F", @"\u00B0"];
NSString *celsius = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@C", @"\u00B0"];
```

Comment: Why not use the symbols directly? There are Unicode characters for this: `NSString *celcius = @"℃"; // U+2103` Same for fahrenheit. No need for string formats for Unicode escapes.

Comment: No. According to [§22.2 of the Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/ch22.pdf), these are provided only for compatibility with legacy encodings. trojanfoe's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, and that is how you would represent the two temperature ranges.  It can be cut down slightly as you don't need to use `stringWithFormat`:

```
NSString *fahrenheit = @"\u00B0F";
NSString *celsius = @"\u00B0C";
```

But you might use `stringWithFormat` to format the actual temperatures along with the symbols etc:

```
float tempInFahrenheit = 23.4f;
float tempInCelsius = 56.8f;
NSString *fahrenheit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f \u00B0F", tempInFahrenheit];
NSString *celsius = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f \u00B0C", tempInCelsius];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"80\u00b0c"];
        [attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-light" size:40.0]
                                          , NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @22} range:NSMakeRange(2, 2)];
        //asign this as a 
examplelabel.attributedtext = attributedString;
```